# Not allowing a component underneath a canvas to be clickable when the canvas is visible in Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, canvas, click

I have a component (a canvas) that has a click event listener on it.  However, there is sometimes an opaque canvas that lays over that component.  When that overlaying canvas is visible, I don't want the underlying component to be clickable.

Is there a way to do this without manually removing the click event listener when the overlaying canvas becomes visible and adding back the click event listener when the overlaying canvas becomes invisible?

As a side note, interestingly enough, the overlaying canvas contains label elements and when the overlaying canvas is visible, the underlaying component is only clickable for the area of the overlaying canvas where there is not a label element.

Also, since this is Flex, I should note that the click event listener was originally added through Actionscript and not through mxml.

Comment: You could always put a check in your `Canvas` click event handler to see if the opaque canvas `visibility` property is set to true before running any additional code.

Comment: @Jason Thanks, that should work on the click event logic.  Similarly though, I also don't want there to be the hand cursor when the mouse is over the visible overlaying canvas (and there is the underlying component underneath).  Is there a way to do that without having to manually change the the hand cursor/button mode properties of the underlying component when the overlaying canvas becomes visible/invisible?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want to do is set `mouseEnabled="true"` and `useHandCursor="false"` on the opaque canvas.  That should stop any mouse events to go 'through' the canvas.

Comment: @J_A_X tried that (as well as mouseEnabled="false"), but the mouse events are still going through the opaque canvas.  it's interesting to me that the mouse events are only going through the parts of the opaque canvas where there is not a label there in the opaque canvas, which makes me think that there should be some property on the opaque canvas to stop mouse events going through it completely

Comment: I set mouseEnabled="false" for the underlying click component on the mouseOver event for the opaque canvas (and vice versa on mouseOut).  That seems to work pretty neatly.

Comment: I wouldn't do that, but that's just me.

Comment: @J_A_X I think your solution might not have worked in this case because the click event listeners are being added manually through actionscript later on, after all the components had already been created.  Could that be it?

Comment: nope, it shouldn't matter when they're added.  Why are you using actionscript to create your components for a Flex project?

Comment: i'm creating the components through MXML in flex but adding the click events through AS because need to be able to dynamically remove or change them later on

Comment: Okay, seems weird but alright.  I can't really comment more though without some code.

Comment: i assume that by default, the overlaying opaque canvas should not be receiving click events from the underlying canvas.  let me know if that's not the case.  there's probably something weird i did along the way.  though i have that quick fix for now, will try to pull out some code later on since it's bugging me what it could be.

Comment: Actually, I believe it should because Canvas' don't capture mouse events by default unless you specify otherwise if memory serves me right.  The opaque canvas essentially needs to 'interrupt' the mouse event for the other canvas, and it can do that simply by having it's own mouse events.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Just setting mouseEnabled="true" and useHandCursor="false" was not enough to accomplish that in this case.  However, once I add any mouse event of its own to the opaque canvas, such as a mouseDown event that does nothing, then it works.

Comment: I added the code:     mouseDown="topCanvas.x = topCanvas.x"   Kind of silly to have to do that.  I'm sure there is a better way without resorting to that although it works pretty easily enough

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure if you set the [mouseEnabled](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#mouseEnabled) and [mouseFocusEnabled](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#mouseFocusEnabled) properties to false, then the canvas will not fire the click event handler.

Of course, I didn't think canvases (or any Container) could be Clickable; so for the event to fire; there has to be something inside the canvas that actually fires the click event.  I'm not sure if the mouseEnabled and mouseFocusEnabled properties trickle down to the container's children.

Comment: See comment to JAX.  The underlying canvas is essentially a border canvas for an image, so it's actually the image that is firing the click event I suppose.

Comment: @Steven Based on your comments; if I had to guess; the mouseEnabled/mouseFocusEnabled prevent the canvas from firing the events, not from listening to the events.  Is the 'border' a child of the main Canvas?

Comment: Not directly, the border is a child of another larger canvas, which is a child of the main canvas.  I found a quick fix as stated in comments to JAX but still bugging me what might be wrong.  I'm assuming that by default, the overlaying canvas should not be receiving click events from the underlying canvas.

Comment: @Steven I'm having some trouble envisioning exactly what is going on.  I think to get a clear explanation you're going to have to show some code.

Answer (score 0):

Just mask the opaque canvas so it wont be over the canvas with the click effect